# android AutoComplete doesn't fit screen

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I'm trying to have an AutoCompleteTextView widget in the bottom of my screen, but of course the autocomplete options are not shown because of the keyboard ...

Any tips ? Perhaps it's possible to the the suggestions box opened upwards ?

(used Android's [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-autocomplete.html) to check it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add this to your activity in the manifest :

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"
```

> The activity's main window is always resized to make room for the soft keyboard on screen

or

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"
```

> he activity's main window is not resized to make room for the soft keyboard. Rather, the contents of the window are automatically panned so that the current focus is never obscured by the keyboard and users can always see what they are typing

Depending on what suits your needs

Comment: it didn't work .. the keyboard still overlaps with the options.